# Cleaning a text with several quotation marks leaving just a pair of them

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

How one could replace a text that contains several of the following pattern with just the necessary quotation marks?

```
Provide we with """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""This is what matters"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""".
```

The result should be:

```
Provide we with "This is what matters".
```

I already have tried this, but it didn't work  well:

```
 gsub("\"\"", "\"", txt)
```

Also, these texts are not with the same number of quotes, so there are ones with fewer quotes while other with even more quotes.

Comment: Use `gsub("[[:punct:]]","",string)` to remove all special characters. There's some useful prebuilt `regex` patterns in `?regex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing each pair of `""` with `"` when you have multiple consecutive occurrences will result in several consecutive double quotation marks to still remain in the string. You want either to match 1 or more `"` chars and replace with a single `"`, or match and remove any `"` that is followed with `"`.

You may use

```
gsub('"+', '"', txt)
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/M1Kvy1)

The `"+` pattern matches one or more double quotation marks and replaces the chunks with a single quotation mark.

With `stringr::str_remove_all`, you can use a regex that will match any `"` that is followed with `"`:

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(txt, '"(?=")')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nfts3V/1). The regex here contains a `(?=")` positive lookahead that requires the presence of `"` immediately to the right of the current location.

Same concept may be conveyed in base R with a PCRE regex (use `perl=TRUE`):

```
gsub('"(?=")', '"', txt, perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `str_remove_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(txt, '"+')
```